# Unable to set bash environment path fed from lines in a config file

Tags: bash, scope

I'm trying to set the path for the PERL5LIB using a simple config file like this:

```
cat /Users/me/.local/bash.d/perl5lib_dirs | while read line
do
case ":$PERL5LIB:" in
  *:$line:*) :;;
  *) echo 'Adding path: '$line; PERL5LIB="$line:";;
esac
done
```

Apparently, since the loop is opened in a subshell, the value of the PERL5LIB variable is lost when the loop exits.

So how else can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the loop to read from the file with input [redirection](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#REDIRECTION) (thus avoiding the subshell):

```
while read line; do
    case ":$PERL5LIB:" in
        *:$line:*) :;;
        *) echo 'Adding path: '$line; PERL5LIB="$line:";;
    esac
done < /Users/me/.local/bash.d/perl5lib_dirs
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the game try sourcing the file.

for example
abc.sh

```
abc=123
```

```
sh abc.sh
echo $abc

source abc.sh
echo $abc
123
```